# Turkey Fry Smoking Oil

Tags: deep-frying, turkey

I am trying to deep fry a turkey for the first time. I let the oil get too hot and it was smoking very heavily for several minutes (10 minutes), but I was able to get the temp down where its not smoking anymore.

Is my turkey likely ruined cooking in this oil? Should I not risk serving it to my family, even if it appears to be OK?

Comment: Was the turkey in the oil while it was smoking? Are you sure it was smoke and not steam?

Comment: A little oil can produce a lot of smoke.  Oil might be OK.  Try like a wing.

Answer (score 1):

Overheating oil causes it to break down, which, at minimum produces off flavors and poor performance.  There is some concern about adverse health effects, depending on the type of oil, but in a cursory search, I found nothing definitive. Most do recommend discarding the oil.

Comment: _"adverse health effects"_ Note that any such are long-term effects. It's not like you'll have food poisoning symptoms.